# If Xavier kept taking his "medication" in the '70s, how we end up in the prologue scene of X3, acknowledging the events of DoFP?

Tags: x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-days-of-future-past, marvel

In X-Men: DoFP a significant alteration of the timeline is occurred. For a moment let's ignore that alteration. We are in 1973 and Professor X keeps taking his medication for the next few years in order for him to walk -which has the side effect of losing his mental powers. How Xavier ends up in the '80s, when we see him in the beginning of X-Men 3 **both walking and also having his mutant powers**? Is that a continuity error or is it explained somehow? I know that Singer doesn't like the events of X-Men 3, therefore he acknowledges what happened in that movie in X-Men DoFP (for instance, Cyclops is absent from the future scenes because he was killed in X3).

*Note to duplicate report:* This question is trying to explain why Professor X is seen walking and having his mental powers at the beginning of X-Men 3 (early '80s), while in X-Men DoFP it is explicitly mentioned that **the treatment for his spine has affected his powers**. The linked question, though, is trying to explain why Xavier walks in early '80s after being shot from Magneto at the end of X-Men: First Class, **ignoring the events of DoFP**.

Comment: Fairly sure this is a continuity error, but I don’t have anything to back that up.

Comment: I've already looked that post, the person who posted and all those who answered it try to explain it ignoring the events of DoFP.

Comment: I thought it was a point that the reason he doesn't have his powers is because he takes *too much* of Hank's serum, seeing as how Hank can still access his Beast abilities at will.

Comment: It's never fully explained, but I just assumed that in the years following, either he scaled back the dosage or Hank altered the formula.

Comment: @Monty129
Even after your explanation, I still don't get why he decided to return to his *old life* (meaning to completely scrap the formula and be paralyzed again), if Hank found out the right balance between having Xavier able-bodied and mental-powered.
I hope that *X-Men: Apocalypse* will address the issue since it's taking place during early '80s but then again DoFP changed the timeline so the question may be unanswered...

Comment: IRL, many medicines lose their effectiveness on a patient over time if it's taken for too long or too often.

Comment: Why didn't this question get re-opened. @PiXel1225 did clarify the difference between this and the other question. And it is a legitimately valid question.